# Display xUnit test data from multiple XML files using style sheet

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xslt, xunit

I've written a test using xUnit which uses the MemberData attribute to discover XML files containing test data via this class:

```
internal class XmlDataRetriever
{
    private const String XmlPath = @"..\..\TestCases\";

    public static IEnumerable<TestCase[]> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return
                CreateTestCases(
                    Directory.GetFiles(XmlPath, "*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                    .ToReadOnlyCollection());
        }
    }

    private static List<TestCase[]> CreateTestCases(ReadOnlyCollection<String> filePaths)
    {
        return
            filePaths
                .Select(testCaseName =>
                    new TestCase[] { new XmlParser().GetTestCase(testCaseName) })
                .ToList();
    }
}
```

The code here's not so important but it gives an idea of how the test cases are discovered.

What I'd like to achieve is some way of viewing a list of these XML test cases in one document, ideally from within Visual Studio, but I'm not sure on the best way to accomplish this.

I have looked into using XSLT, but this only gets me half the way there, as I'd still need some way of discovering the test cases and displaying them all together.

Comment: When you have multiple xml files appended together (an array at the root level) is called "not well formed" although it meets xml standards.  What I sometimes do is to create a dummy root element : <Root>(add files here)</Root> and then add all the individual xml files to the root.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. I'd still need some sort of automated process to compile this parent XML though.

Comment: I usually just use streamreader to read file and skip the first line of each file (the identification line) and then just combine under the root element.  Pretty simple to do.  Will post example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of combining xml files

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const String XmlPath = @"..\..\TestCases\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<Root>";
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(XmlPath))
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.UTF8);
                //skip identification line
                reader.ReadLine();
                xml += reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            xml += "</Root>";
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use xml linq then try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const String XmlPath = @"..\..\TestCases\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement xRoot = new XElement("Root");
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(XmlPath))
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
                XElement root = doc.Root;
                xRoot.Add(root);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I may end up doing this but, Ideally, I wanted a way to do this outside of any compiled code.

I'd like to somehow be able to just host a document that collated all the XML files.

Having non-technical people on our team running console applications from VS is just a bit too far at this stage.

I suppose I could try to use your idea as part of the build process. Definitely something to look into. Thanks!

Comment: You can create a bat file to do equivalent.